# How to center gridview?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I tried solutions found in other posts but none of them seems to work in my code.
Here is a piece of code:
EDIT: updated, removed one RelativeLayout, still not centered

```
GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
HallAdapter hallAdapter = new HallAdapter(this, listOfSeats);
gridView.setNumColumns(columnCount);
gridView.setAdapter(hallAdapter);
ZoomView zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
zoomView.addView(gridView);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.infoTextView);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    relativeLayoutMain.addView(zoomView, params);
```

I think that i have to add some LayoutParameters, but I don't know where.
Part of XML file of activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
```

This is how its look now:
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT:
I wonder is it look like this? Or am I wrong?
[image]

Comment: A standard approach to centering is to hold Max values for height and width and to position things at maxheigh/2 and max width/2

Comment: you can try `setHorizontalGravity` and `setVerticalGravity`

Comment: change xml property 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
in GridView Tag

Comment: `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: @pawkondr did you try my solution

Comment: Look at this picture i added, is it look like this or zoomview is stick to relativelayoutforzoom?

Comment: @pawkondr what is the zoomview's width?

Comment: I don't know i didn't set it. It is probably default

Comment: I found that zoomview has height of parent which is RelativeLayoutMain

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

for programetically
gridview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: By positiveButton you mean "next" button?

Comment: If so, button is in the center of the screen and grid view is in old place

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this

```
GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
        HallAdapter hallAdapter = new HallAdapter(this, listOfSeats);
        gridView.setNumColumns(columnCount);
        gridView.setAdapter(hallAdapter);
        ZoomView zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
        zoomView.addView(gridView);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutForZoom = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.infoTextView);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        relativeLayoutForZoom.addView(zoomView);


        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        relativeLayoutMain.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        relativeLayoutMain.addView(relativeLayoutForZoom,params);
```

Comment: Ok i agree, but to which object? To gridview?

Comment: @pawkondr yes to the gridview.

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        gridView.setLayoutParams(p); I tried this and its not working.

Comment: @pawkondr actually how its looking?

Comment: Still same as at the beggining

Comment: @pawkondr remove the line gravity and try once?

Answer (score 0):

Use layout params when adding the view

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

relativeLayoutMain.addView(relativeLayoutForZoom, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

After second look at your question I have another answer.
Do you need relativeLayoutForZoom at all?

```
GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
HallAdapter hallAdapter = new HallAdapter(this, listOfSeats);
gridView.setNumColumns(columnCount);
gridView.setAdapter(hallAdapter);
ZoomView zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
zoomView.addView(gridView);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.infoTextView);

RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
relativeLayoutMain.addView(zoomView, params);
```

Comment: I heed it to set that gridView is above textfield: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.infoTextView);

Comment: You can add this param for the zoomView as in this answer. No need to wrap zoomView in another layout.

Comment: You were right i removed aditional relative layout but still not centered

Comment: Your RealitveLayout is set to wrap content. Make it match parent, then you will have full width and the zoomView will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Set layout parameters of `zoomView` to `params` and add the rule to params as `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

Regards,

Comment: set your main `RelativeLayout` width and height to `match_parent` and then Set layout parameters of `zoomView` to `params` and add the rule to `params` as `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
gridview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

[![ android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jprmU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jprmU.png)

Comment: Problem is that i don't have this gridview in xml

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

along with `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.infoTextView);`

Comment: set RelativeLayout height and width to match_parent in XML

Comment: It didn't change anything